# SQL Server- The provided statistics stream is corrupt

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to add statistics to a table that I already created. When I tried to run it, it throws an error:

> The provided statistics stream is corrupt

This is my query for an example of a stats:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM sys.stats 
               WHERE name = N'_WA_Sys_00000027_3C69FB99' 
                 AND object_id = object_id(N'[dbo].[PromotionEvent]'))
    CREATE STATISTICS [_WA_Sys_00000027_3C69FB99] 
        ON [dbo].[PromotionEvent]([CRMCode]) 
        WITH STATS_STREAM = 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
GO
```

Why do I get this error? Is it because the stream is too long? How do I fix this?
I have to stick with this stream  because I am doing data archiving so the stats must have similar name.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to run DBCC CHECKDB against your DB, it looks like you have corrupted system table with ID 60 holding information about object in your DB.

jaromora;
go

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

> DBCC CHECKTABLE(YourTableName, REPAIR_REBUILD )

While performing above operation ensure that your database is in a single user mode.

**If this doesn't work then you can try to drop the primary key of the table and recreate it.**

Also if the issue is still not resolved then; the last option would be:

> DBCC CHECKTABLE(YourTableName, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)

Comment: use below command for single user,    ALTER DATABASE DBName SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
DBCC CHECKTABLE(TableName, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
GO
ALTER DATABASE DBName SET MULTI_USER;
GO